# JAX-WS ServiceConstructionException

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, jax-ws

We're stuck with a simple webservice integration. We developed a client webservice and deployed it to customer server. Server has no internet access and throws a connection timeout error for xmlmime.xsd (http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime). So we downloaded the XSD and updated the schemaLocation in WSDL as shown below to fix the error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:cmn="http://schemas.companyh.com/SM/7/Common" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.companyh.com/SM/7" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" targetNamespace="http://schemas.companyh.com/SM/7" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/  http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.companyh.com/SM/7"
               attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
               targetNamespace="http://schemas.companyh.com/SM/7" version="2017-06-14 Rev 0">
        <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" schemaLocation="./xmlmime.xsd" />
        <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.companyh.com/SM/7/Common" schemaLocation="./Common.xsd" />
        <xs:complexType name="IncidentExternalOffenseKeysType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="source.id" nillable="true" type="cmn:StringType" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="query" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
            <xs:attribute name="updatecounter" type="xs:long" use="optional" />
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="IncidentExternalOffenseInstanceType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AlarmId" nillable="true" type="cmn:StringType" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EventName" nillable="true" type="cmn:StringType" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IncidentId" nillable="true" type="cmn:StringType" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SourceUser" nillable="true" type="cmn:StringType" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AlarmRaiseTime" nillable="true" type="cmn:DateTimeType" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Qid" nillable="true" type="cmn:StringType" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Payload">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:complexContent>
                            <xs:extension base="cmn:ArrayType">
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Payload" type="cmn:StringType" />
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:complexContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SourceIP" nillable="true" type="cmn:StringType" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Severity" nillable="true" type="cmn:IntType" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ResolveTime" nillable="true" type="cmn:DateTimeType" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IsResolved" nillable="true" type="cmn:BooleanType" />
....
```

But then a new error logged as shown below when we try to call the service. It has become a major problem and i have no idea what to do next.

We'll be glad for everybit of advice.

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 101 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:106)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:460)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:292)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1138)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:441)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
        at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:347)
        at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:345)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:345)
        at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:246)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:472)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:327)
        ... 134 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: null
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:329)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:423)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:525)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:261)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:199)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:91)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:157)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:142)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createPort(ServiceImpl.java:493)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:359)
        ... 123 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:361)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:350)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
        at com.companyh.schemas.sm._7.o.a(SourceFile:81)
        at com.companybt.product.actionplugins.Plugin.a(SourceFile:166)
        at com.companybt.product.actionplugins.Plugin.d(SourceFile:135)
        at com.companybt.product.actionplugins.b.a(SourceFile:68)
        at com.companybt.product.service.DeviceService.b(SourceFile:143)
        at com.companybt.product.service.DeviceService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bed97847.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:652)
        at com.companybt.product.service.DeviceService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6a22438e.b(<generated>)
        at com.companybt.product.restapi.DeviceAPI.test(SourceFile:53)
        at com.companybt.product.restapi.DeviceAPI$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bf38b67d.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
        at com.companybt.product.restapi.DeviceAPI$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$342e1bc3.test(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:59)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:155)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at com.companybt.product.springsecurity.c.doFilterInternal(SourceFile:25)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the problem, its all because of obfuscation. I've just added a line to keep generated classes as is and problem gone. hope this helps others in the future